# Handling multiple return values in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following data:

```
cte
=================
gp_id | m_ids
------|----------
1     | {123}
2     | {432,222}
3     | {123,222}
```

And a function with a signature like this (which in fact returns not a table but a couple of ids):

```
FUNCTION foo(m_ids integer[])
RETURNS TABLE (
    first_id integer,
    second_id integer
)
```

Now, I've got to iterate over each row and perform some calculations with that function, so I would get something like this:

```
gp_id | first_id | second_id 
------|----------|-----------
1     | 25       | 25        
2     | 13       | 24        
3     | 25       | 11
```

To achieve that I tried the following code:

```
SELECT gp_id, 
       ( 
              SELECT * 
              FROM   foo( 
                     ( 
                            SELECT m_ids 
                            FROM   cte c2 
                            WHERE  c2.gp_id = c1.gp_id)) limit 1) 
FROM   cte c1
```

The problem is in the `SELECT *` statement. If I use `SELECT first_id`, everything works well (except for that I have to run two consecutive queries, which I'd like to avoid, obviously), but in the former case I'm getting the error

> subquery must return only one column

which is somewhat expected.
So how can I correctly iterate over the table in one single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function in a lateral join:

```
select gp_id, first_id, second_id
from cte, 
lateral foo(m_ids);
```